Why does the viewport material preview look normal but the viewport rendering looks ugly and messed up?




I'm a beginner and I can't see if anyone else has this problem! It keeps looking so demonic! Help!

Hello and welcome. Please don't crop out essential information from your screenshots, this hides away any details that could possibly hint at what your issue is. As it stands a partial screenshot of the subject without context or further information makes it impossible to diagnose the issue. Please edit your post and replace your images with full uncropped screenshots showing the user interface, properties, and any relevant parameters that might help us solve the issue.

Firs is that you are using two different light and reflection sources, which makes it look different. The first one is and HDR image used by blender, the second one is the sky texture.

There’s almost nothing in the background for the metal to reflect in render except the smooth gradient sky texture, but the material preview in the viewport automatically sets a background HDRI for you (by default of a forest), so you see a much more realistic reflection there. You can set an HDRI in the Shader editor (Blender has some exr ones in its internal data files if you wanna swipe one), just remember add it as an Environment Texture and not an Image Texture, or it won’t map properly. (Yes this is a repeat problem but idk how to search for it as the titles are all different)
